# I'm getting error while running maven application

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I'm getting this error while running the maven application locally. Maven build completed successfully, but while running the application seeing this error

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project imc-ui: An exception occurred while running. null.

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.iodine.imc</groupId>
        <artifactId>imc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>imc-ui</artifactId>
    <name>imc-ui</name>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.7.9</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.9</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <vaadin.spring.version>1.2.0</vaadin.spring.version>
        <vaadin4spring.version>0.0.8-SNAPSHOT</vaadin4spring.version>

        <!-- If addon submodule is not used, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
        <start-class>com.iodine.imc.ui.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>imc-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-ext-security</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-eventbus</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-sidebar</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.spring.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-addon-i18n</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin4spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-treegrid</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
            <artifactId>tableexport-for-vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-combobox-multiselect</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <!-- Widgetset goals for add-ons, including imc-addon -->
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>

                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace output by adding `-X` to maven command?

Comment: The issue is in the mapping between two tables.